# Program in PyQt5 only runs once

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I made a tiny program that takes a few integers from boxes and perform a calculation when a button is clicked, displays the results in a label and a button to clean the boxes and the label.

Everything runs fine, except that it only runs once. If I change the numbers and click again, it does nothing but reprint the last result inside the label.

I just started learning PyQt5, so probably I'm missing something basic.

Thanks!

This is my code:

```
from pulverizadora_ui import *
import formulasPulverizadora


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        QtWidgets.QMainWindow.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.boton_calcular.clicked.connect(self.calcular)

       
        
        # Para que las cajan acepten solo números y que tengan decimales.
        self.caja_caudal_campo.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator()) 
        self.caja_caudal_boquilla.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.caja_velocidad_avance.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())
        self.caja_ancho_labor_boquilla.setValidator(QtGui.QDoubleValidator())


        

        
        
        # Para que los resultados de la etiqueta no se corten:
        self.resultados.setWordWrap(True)

       
        


    
    def calcular(self):
        # Recibe los datos de las cajas y las agrega a la lista "valores":
        caudal_de_campo = self.caja_caudal_campo.text()
        valores.append(caudal_de_campo)


        caudal_de_boquilla = self.caja_caudal_boquilla.text()
        valores.append(caudal_de_boquilla)

        velocidad = self.caja_velocidad_avance.text()
        valores.append(velocidad)

        ancho_de_boquilla = self.caja_ancho_labor_boquilla.text()
        valores.append(ancho_de_boquilla)

        
        
        # Esto usa map() para iterar por la lista valores y aplica la función convertir() a cada valor. Devuelve una nueva lista mapeados:
        mapeados = list(map(convertir, valores))


        

        # CÁLCULOS:
        # Cálculo del caudal de campo (Q), el primer elemento de la lista "mapeados":
        if mapeados[0] == "x":
            caudalCampo = formulasPulverizadora.Q(mapeados[1], mapeados[2], mapeados[3])
            
            self.resultados.setText("El caudal de campo es: " + str(round(caudalCampo, 2)) + " litros por hectárea")
        
        
        # Cálculo del caudal de boquilla (q), el segundo elemento de la lista "mapeados":    
        elif mapeados[1] == "x":
            caudalBoquilla = formulasPulverizadora.q(mapeados[0], mapeados[2], mapeados[3])

            self.resultados.setText("El caudal de boquilla es: " + str(round(caudalBoquilla, 2)) + " litros por minuto.")


        # Cálculo de la velocidad de avance (v), el tercer elemento de la lista "mapeados":    
        elif mapeados[2] == "x":
            velocidadAvance = formulasPulverizadora.v(mapeados[0], mapeados[1], mapeados[3])

            self.resultados.setText("La velocidad de avance es de: " + str(round(velocidadAvance, 2)) + " kilómetros por hora") 



        # Cálculo del ancho de boquilla (a), el cuarto elemento de la lista "mapeados":    
        elif mapeados[3] == "x":
            anchoBoquilla = formulasPulverizadora.a(mapeados[0], mapeados[1], mapeados[2])

            self.resultados.setText("El ancho de labor de cada boquilla es de: " + str(round(anchoBoquilla, 2)) + " metros")           

            

    


# Función usada por el map(): si hay un "" mete una x, y si hay un número como string, lo pasa a un número con decimales:
def convertir(elemento):
    if elemento == "":
        return "x"
    else:
        return float(elemento) 




# Lista que recibe los valores de las cajas al apretar el botón calcular:       
valores = []

        

     



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Looks like you are appending to `valores` each time, map them to `mapeados`, but only use indexes 0, 1, 2, 3 in the latter, so it always operates on the first entered values.

Comment: For future reference, please avoid non-English comments in your code (they are meaningless to most of people, so they are a distraction), and also possibly use English names for objects: while in *your* code you can obviously name things as you like, this is a common place where English is the only accepted language, and code written in that common language is much more easier to read (even to people who speak other languages), which means that *more* people will be more interested in your question, thus increasing the chances to get answers.

Comment: Also, avoid unnecessary blank spaces (read more about this and other important topics in the official [Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)), and remember that it's usually better to provide a [mre]: your code has two imports that are not included, so we cannot *actually* reproduce it, and we're forced to read everything, line by line.

Comment: Thank you VERY much @tromgy , that was the problem. I wasn't updating my list with the values, so I was getting the same over and over. 
Now everything works! :)